# Programmatically retrieve all the owners from a Azure subscription

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api

I want to retrieve the all the Owners of an azure subscription Programmatically. 
I don't want do it using Powershell.

And i came to know that we can achieve this using Azure Management REST API but could not find the exact API reference to retrieve the owner list from a azure subscription.

Can some one please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### REST APIs

You should be able to get that information using the Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments REST API.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2015-07-01&$filter={filter}
```

In your case, since you're looking for Owners at Subscription level, the scope would be         {scope} will be subscriptions/{subscriptionId}

Also,

- Once you get the response, it will contain Role Definitions IDs instead of exact names. For all Built-in Roles, you can know which Role it is before hand by visiting this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/list). E.g. Id for [Owner role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner) is "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
- To find the Id's for all possible Role Definitions as part of response, you can use [Role Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/list) REST API

**Helpful Documentation**

Read through this Microsoft Documentation which gives details on how to List out, Grant Access or Remove Access using RBAC and REST API : [Manage Access Using RBAC and REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest)

### UPDATE (Samples and API to get to Classic Administrators as well)

I ran a few samples using my trial subscription. Here are the requests and responses.

1. To find all the users who have been explicitly assigned "Owner" role at the subscription level

   Request:

   ```
   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{my subscription GUID}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2018-01-01-preview
   ```

   Response:

NOTICE That Role Definition Id in response is "8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635". This corresponds to built-in Owner role.

```
    {"value":[{"properties":{"roleDefinitionId":"/subscriptions/{my Subscription GUID}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635","principalId":"{some user GUID}","principalType":"User","scope":"/subscriptions/{my Subscription GUID}","createdOn":"2018-10-03T05:12:52.7213301Z","updatedOn":"2018-10-03T05:12:52.7213301Z","createdBy":"GUID","updatedBy":"GUID"},"id":"/subscriptions/{my Subscription GUID}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/83eee76b-4a0d-4f61-8c62-409501e95457","type":"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments","name":"83eee76b-4a0d-4f61-8c62-409501e95457"}]}
```

2. To find all the users who are Owners by the virtue of being Classic Administrators (This is relevant for accounts that sign up for a subscription, but haven't been explicitly assigned Owner role using Azure portal RBAC)

   Request: Notice classicAdministrators at the end of URL and the API Version is an old one 2015-06-01

   GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/6f070baf-bbba-47a5-bbe4-a0450017cdf5/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/classicAdministrators?api-version=2015-06-01

   Response: Notice role is ServiceAdministrator;AccountAdministrator

   ```
   {"value":[{"properties":{"emailAddress":"xxxx@xxxx.com","role":"ServiceAdministrator;AccountAdministrator"},"id":"/subscriptions/{mysubscriptionguid}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/classicAdministrators/00030000B1F89CF0","type":"Microsoft.Authorization/classicAdministrators","name":"00030000B1F89CF0"}]}
   ```

Comment: @Avinash did the samples help? or are you facing any issues?